# How can i determine character encoding?

Tags: python, arrays, string, windows, character-encoding

I have a string in python - b'&\xc1\xba\xda\xc5\x9b\xea\xba\x11\xd3@\x13/\xdf%8g\xf1# \x11\x8fp&'
I want to decode it, but for this utf-8 doesn't work. Can you help me, how can i determine character encoding?

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid string? You can try decoding it with 'ISO-8859-1' like so:
`b'&\xc1\xba\xda\xc5\x9b\xea\xba\x11\xd3@\x13/\xdf%8g\xf1# \x11\x8fp&'.decode('ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527728/11318161